# Wordpress Video Portal

Tags: php, wordpress, video

my challenge is to built a video portal, based on wordpress (blog already started).
so in the backend there must be a option to add, tag, descripe videos and in frontend the videos must have a comment function, must be searchable and so on.

wordpress gives already a large amout of functionallity and i want to use this, comments for example, but also categorisation and tagging.

what is the best practise to built such a "plugin" ?
where to start? what to use?

custom tables and built everything by myself or can i use the blog functionallity to advantage?

hopefully everything is clear, comment if not ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [VideoPress](http://videopress.com/).

Comment: something like that yes, but we need to built it ourself. its not exaclty what i need. i have to built a page (frontend) where you can see, the most seen, the newest, the top10 and so on.